# Programatically click on a div root to open the content that internally gets open using java scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to click on the div class (_2wP_Y) below programatically in order to open a part of the screen which display certain content using javascript internally.

```
<div class="_2wP_Y" style="z-index: 3; height: 72px; transform: translateY(72px);">
<div tabindex="-1">
    <div class="_2EXPL CxUIE _1f1zm">
      ....
      ....
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried various ways to click on HTMLDivElement object. Console log printing on website as clicked but on screen it doesn't get clicked automatically.

Codes I tried

```
     var HTMLDivElement =   document.getElementsByClassName('_2wP_Y')
     HTMLDivElement.onclick = function() {
            console.log("Clicked " );

        }

    var clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
        "view": window,
        "bubbles": true,
        "cancelable": false
    });

       HTMLDivElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

It prints Clicked on console.
I also tried `HTMLDivElement.click();`
It also print Clicked on console, but click doesn't happen on browser.

There is multiple div having same class name(_2wP_Y) and I am using Chrome for testing in Ubuntu.

Basically I am trying to click on div on left side part of the image below to open the groups messages content in the middle of the section.

[image]

Comment: javascript is not java script, and is definitely not java. ...

Comment: Either use inline `onclick` event in the `div` tag or hide the part of the screen on `page load` and display when you need.

Comment: There is no onclick in div tag.

Comment: As long as you reference the element properly, `HTMLDivElement[0]`, that code works as is, on Chrome/Windows. The issue you might have here is your `transform`, which how it is setup now, makes no sense, and can cause cross browser issues. Elaborate on that, and we might be able to suggest a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope this will work, happy coding :)

```js
var HTMLDivElement =   document.getElementsByClassName('_2wP_Y')

    HTMLDivElement[0].addEventListener("onclick", function(){
        console.log("clicked")
        HTMLDivElement[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";

    })

    HTMLDivElement[0].dispatchEvent(new Event("onclick"));
```

```html
<div class="_2wP_Y" style="z-index: 3; height: 72px; transform: translateY(72px);">
<div tabindex="-1">
    <div class="_2EXPL CxUIE _1f1zm">
      ....
      ....
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer the question. Its printing clicked and true . I tried this already and got same result. 

Its internally clicking and returning true , but on browser I can not see click or colour changes of div. :(

Comment: thats strange, i hope we are also running code in browsers :). So you mentioned in the question like the div needs to open can you elaborate on that section. So as my understanding the div is initially loaded but it may be hidden or closed div. once js loads you need to either show or open the div.

Comment: I ran the code using console as well line by line and along with java script chrome extension. There is multiple div having same class name(_2wP_Y) and I am using Chrome for testing in Ubuntu.

Is it because of that ?

Comment: You are right div is hidden, I can not see in source code but I can see div in console after page is loaded. After loading the page only I am running the codes.

Comment: can you recreate the exact pblm with some amount of code. in jsfiddle or codepen .So we can have a look through on that one.

Comment: Please have a look at the question again I have added the screenshot of the screen with inspect html

Comment: Recreated the question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51421755/click-on-a-div-element-dynamically?noredirect=1#comment89814499_51421755

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that the dom is not yet loaded, resulting in the onclick event not really being attached to the DOM element. Another issue could be that `getElementsByClassName` returns an array and not a single element (like `getElementById` would). So if you only have one object with that particular class, you can just use `HTMLDivElement[0]`

Try to wrap everything within `window.onload = function() {};`:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var HTMLDivElement = document.getElementsByClassName('_2wP_Y');
    HTMLDivElement[0].onclick = function() {
        console.log("Clicked");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrapping onclick inside  `window.onload = function() {console.log("Inside winows.load funciton");  var HTMLDivElement = document.getElementsByClassName('_2wP_Y');
    HTMLDivElement[0].onclick = function() {
        console.log("Clicked");
    } }`  Clicked is not getting printed. Even  `console.log("Inside winows.load funciton"); `  is not getting printed

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery.

```js
//handling click event
$("._2wP_Y").click(function() {
  alert("I was clicked");
})


//click itself
$("._2wP_Y").click();
```

```html
<div class="_2wP_Y">i was clicked</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```